# VSCode's python debugging and testing tool automatically loads .env

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pydantic

I have two .env files called `.env` and `.test.env`
I'm loading my pydantic settings using the `env_file = ".test.env"` like this:

```py
from pydantic import BaseSettings

class Settings(BaseSettings):
    A: int

    class Config:
        env_file = ".test.env"
        env_file_encoding = "utf-8"


settings = Settings()
```

This works fine when I run the script from terminal like:

```bash
uvicorn run:app
```

But, when I use the VScode Debugging or Testing, it overrides env values set in *.test.env* with values from *.env*

My *launch.json*:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Module",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "uvicorn",
            "args": [
                "run:app",
                "--reload"
            ],
            "justMyCode": true
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I stop VScode from exporting the *.env* file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out there is a setting in vscode called `Python: Env File` with path to env file. Removing the path solved the problem.